# Converting Hex Color Code to Color Name in Python

Tags: python, colors, hex, converters

How to convert hex color code to color name?

Example:
Hexa Color Code : #123456
It should return the color name as **Blue Zodiac**.

Comment: Which is your set of colour data? Colours name are arbitrary, and various standards do not agree on colour<->colour-name (note: most colour names are outside standards, so situation is worst). Some databases use trademarked colours (so with restricted usage)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there are libraries to do this in python the only solution I came with is to use [this github project](https://github.com/meodai/color-names) it has 29000 color names to access this huge list you need to use apis you can find further more description in the link above